# PHP OOP: How to get database rows as objects?

Tags: php, oop

I can do this when selecting a single row fine but cant quite get my head around doing this for multiple rows of data.

For the single row I simply instantiate a new object that does a number of operations behind the scenes that bascially produces a row from the database as our object.

**Example:**

```
$object = new Classname($param);
foreach($object->row as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.":".$value."\n";
}

//output
id:1
firstname:steve
lastname:took
etc...
```

Any clever people here able to point me in the right direction please?

NOTE: just want to be able to create an object for each row rather than the one object with nested arrays

EDIT: sorry $object->row is a member of the class that stores selected row from the database

Comment: heh? whats the issue? whats does `$object->row` contain at the moment?

Comment: sorry $object->row is a member of the class that stores selected row from the database

Comment: So `$object->row` is a member that contains an array of assoc. arrays, which you want to be turned into an object? Thing is, no matter what you do you'll deal with arrays, so I don't see why you're trying to convert it all to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you consider to use an ORM (Object Relational Mapper), like Doctrine or Propel? 
I prefer Doctrine: http://www.doctrine-project.org/
Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks DS, think this would answer it.

Comment: Thank you for your vote :) Try these libs, at least Doctrine: is awesome!

Answer (score 6):

If I got you the answer is pretty simple `mysql_fetch_object`

Example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->user_id;
    echo $row->fullname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
class users extends db {

    public $users_id = 0;
    public $users_group = 0;
    public $users_firstname = 0;
    public $users_lastname = 0;

    public function open($id) {
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_id = '$id'";
            $res = parent::DB_SELECT($sql);
            if (mysql_num_rows($res) <> 1) {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users " . $id;
            $res = parent::DB_SELECT($sql);
            if (mysql_num_rows($res) <= 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }


        $data = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $this->users_id = $row['users_id'];
            $this->users_group = $row['users_group'];
            $this->users_firstname = $row['users_firstname'];
            $this->users_lastname = $row['users_lastname'];
            $data[] = (array) $this;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function setUsersId($users_id) { $this->users_id = addslashes($users_id); }
    public function getUsersId() { return stripslashes($this->users_id); }

    public function setUsersGroup($users_group) { $this->users_group = addslashes($users_group); }
    public function getUsersGroup() { return stripslashes($this->users_group); }

    public function setUsersFirstname($users_firstname) { $this->users_firstname = addslashes($users_firstname); }
    public function getUsersFirstname() { return stripslashes($this->users_firstname); }

    public function setUsersLastname($users_lastname) { $this->users_lastname = addslashes($users_lastname); }
    public function getUsersLastname() { return stripslashes($this->users_lastname); }
}
```

Comment: Well its OO php, Users would be the table so this is a class named the same, you instantiate it by $users = new Users(); The db is simple a top class containing methods to communicate with the Database. The DB_SELECT pretty much returns the result from a mysql_query($sql, $connection);

Comment: @yes123, what about useless? Its fantastic to have your tables in separate classes.

Comment: @yes123, well it's a strongly typed class (you probably know about them) in this case i just skipped the datatyping, and so what if I call a parent method DB_SELECT, thats one line dude, chill.

Comment: @yes123, declaring to someone that their "code is just awful" is incredibly rude.  You need to take some time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq); in particular, **Be Nice**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQLi.

```
// Connect
$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');

// Query
$users = $db->query('SELECT * from users');

// Loop
while($user = $users->fetch_object()) {
    echo $users->field;
}

// Close
$users->close();
$db->close();
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php